# Drupal 7 calling Video Embed Field from template file?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am using this https://drupal.org/project/video_embed_field module to take in a video url and in the template file I have this array

[image]

How can I render it? Is there something similar to theme_image_style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using this

```
$video_data = $media_item->field_media_video[$node->language][0];
$video_data['style'] = 'video_style_to_use';
$video_data['url'] = $video_data['video_url'];
template_preprocess_video_embed_field_embed_code($video_data);
$temp_media .= "<div class='media'>";
$temp_media .= $video_data['embed_code'];
$temp_media .= "</div>";
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it in a more clean way, you should:

```
print theme('video_embed_field_embed_code', array('url' => $video['video_url']));
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use drupal render :

```
print render($content['field_media_video']);
```

replace this $content['field_media_video'] with your object/array.

If you want to change some parameters do it before the render.

Comment: I wish it had been that simple.